# IndexError: list index out of range. Why do I get this error in the second function but not the first function?

Tags: python

The function **derivative** computes the derivative of a polynomial; the degree of each entry needs to be reduced by one, each entry must be multiplied by the previous degree, and the term at degree[0] needs to be removed.

This code

```
lst = [1,2,3] """This list represents the polynomial 3x^2+2x+1"""

"""This function moves each entry one index down and removes the last 
entry"""

def move(lst):
    copy = list(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i-1] = copy[i]
    del lst[-1]
    print lst

move(lst)
```

produces this:

```
Samuels-MacBook:python barnicle$ python problemset2.py
[2, 3]
```

This code:

```
def derivative(poly):
    copy = list(poly)
    degree = 0
    for i in range(len(poly)):
        i = degree*(i+1) 
        poly[i-1] = copy[i]
        degree += 1
    del poly[-1]
    print poly

derivative(lst)
```

produces this error:

```
Samuels-MacBook:python barnicle$ python problemset2.py

     Traceback (most recent call last):   File "problemset2.py", line 59,
     in <module>
         derivative(lst)   File "problemset2.py", line 55, in derivative
         poly[i-1] = copy[i] IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, I figured it out. Here is my new, working function, renamed ddx2:

```
lst = [0,3,5,4] #lst represents the polynomial 4x^3+3x^2+5x
def ddx2(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] = lst[i]*i
        if i != 0:
            lst[i-1] = lst[i]
    del lst[-1]
    print lst
ddx2(lst) #Here I call the function
```

When I call the function, I get the correct derivative in the correct format, i.e. [3,10,12]. I think the error message I was getting was because I was trying to shorten the length of the list before I exited the loop.

Comment: Add some debugging statements by printing out the value of `i` within the loop before and after you set it to `degree*(i+1)`. You will see what you are doing.

Comment: Instead of `move`, you can simply do `my_list[:-1]`

Answer (score 2):

The line `i = degree*(i+1)` basically means squared index. You have array of length `i`, but trying to get element with index `i*i`.

Comment: It's even worse. `degree` is the same as `i`, so it's `i = i * (i+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

the index `i` with its computation `i = degree*(i+1)` will grow equal or larger than `len(poly)` and `len(copy)` and hence out of range

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick hack I did :) Hope it meets your requirements, you just gotta be aware of lists length.

```
lst = [1,2,3] 


dlist=[]
derivate=[]
for i in range(len(lst)): #Here you multiply the coeficients by the power
    dlist.append(lst.__getitem__(i)*i)
#print dlist
for m in range(len(dlist)): #In the derivate the constants become zero
    if dlist.__getitem__(m) != 0:
        derivate.append(dlist.__getitem__(m))
print lst
print derivate
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! Yes list length is what I had to be aware of. I appreciate your help, I really wanted to do this one (almost) on my own tho. BTW, isn't _getitem_ a class method or something? I'm not quite there yet! Thanks!!!